# how to redirect one page to another page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

this is my Controller:

```
  @Controller
    public class WebRedirectController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcome() {
            return "welcome";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String redirect() {
            return "redirect:finalPage";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String finalPage() {
            return "final";
        }
    }
```

servletContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemalocation="  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava.controller">
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This Exception I am getting when i run the application :

Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 65; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

please tell me where i am doing mistake i try to solve this issue but still unable to fix please suggest me .

Comment: The error you are getting is completely unrelated to rhe question you are asking. Check your xml. Check that you have the appropriate Spring libraries on your classpath.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/HFVEJBgDjyU6pscDWmKdeL  this is web.xml @ Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: The error refers to the `sdnext-servlet.xml` file. Cross-check if it's valid, if you still cannot find the error, please paste that file here,

Comment: Please post the contents of sdnext-servlet.xml here.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/MVTUzKVm8eaKPcF8sx8hGM

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should add this in your XML document

1. contextConfigLocation
   /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml